# failed to capture snapshot of input files for task android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make android studio project,

I was run project in Android Device Manager is fine,
but when I try to run on a real device I have some error:

```
Error:Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug' property 'otherFileInputs' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file 'C:\Users\psd1-pc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar'.
```

my real device have Lollipop Android,
what do I do for resolve this problem

thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Instant Run enabled, you need to build and run the project with the same api level. A debug app build with Instant Run for a specific api will only work for the same api level in the real device.

If you want to run the app, please turn off Instant Run, then rebuild the app.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful,

Comment: You're very welcome. If this answer helps you, please accept it to close the thread.