# I have Some Error when add Button to my React Native App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

** I have some issue when adding just Button !!**

and in the app that's the error

> java.lang.string cannot be cast to
>   com.facebook.react.uimanager.accessibility
>   DelegateUtil$accessibilityRole

[image: Error Button]

---

my simple code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TextInput, View, Button, Text } from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    placeName: ""
  };

  placeNameChangeHandler = val => {
    this.setState({
      placeName: val
    });
  };

  onPressLearnMore = () => {
    alert("Pressed");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button
          onPress={this.onPressLearnMore}
          title="Learn More"
          color="#841584"    
        />

        <TextInput
          style={{
            width: 300,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            borderBottomColor: "#333"
          }}
          placeholder="Enter Name.."
          value={this.state.placeName}
          onChangeText={this.placeNameChangeHandler}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: So if you delete `Button` your code works normally?

Comment: @Think-Twice I know it's not related! but that's is I show!

Comment: @JoseVf yes! it's work, it's so weird

Comment: @Gha which version of react-native are you using?

Comment: @Think-Twice "react-native": "0.57.3"

Comment: Its a bug check here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21754

Comment: @Think-Twice yes!! the bug is this version , i test the Code in old project and run without bugs , Now how to back the old version "0.57.2" after init the new project !? any ideas !

Comment: @Gha I would suggest you to delete the node_modules folder and replace this version "0.57.2" in package.json file without this ^. then do npm i

Comment: @Think-Twice can you please update all this in your answer!

Comment: @Gha I updated my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when trying to use Button in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782396/error-when-trying-to-use-button-in-react-native)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yeah, it's a bug in `react-native 0.57.3` but `react-native 0.57.2` has its own issues!

So you have to downgrade to `react-native 0.57.1` that is a bit more stable!

Do the following things in command prompt in the root directory of your project (these steps install some missed dependencies of this version):

1) delete your `node_modules` directory (command: `rmdir node_modules /s` in windows)

2) `npm i -S react-native@0.57.1`

3) `npm add @babel/runtime`

4) `npm i -D schedule@0.4.0`

5) `npm i`

now you can safely run `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`.

hope this works for you (as it does for me).

Comment: WTF! it's work Now :/ anyway thank u, bro, I have one Question, what's the right Command to init the new project without the last version? I do something like this ** react-native init myApp react-native@0.57.1**, but doesn't work and initial the last version 0.57.3!

Comment: you should add [VERBOSE] such this:
eeact-native init myApp react-native --version 0.57.1

Comment: @Gha your welcome! if you want to create a new project with specific version (let's say 0.57.1) you can run `react-native init projectName --version@0.57.1`.

Comment: @AliRadmanesh thank u , i have some issue when i install react-navigation , i have bug " The development server returned response code:500 " what's this ?

Comment: @Gha your question is not in the scope of this topic. You can ask another question in stackoverflow. But before that make sure to search the error you've got. good luck!

Comment: You sir, Ali Radmanesh, you are a lifesaver. Internet is useful because of good people like you <3

Comment: @JitheshKt Thank you. yeah, Internet and specially Stackoverflow is a lifesaver for developers :)

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in `react-native version 0.57.3` so downgrading `react-native` version to `0.57.1` would be the workaround

Change the react-native version in package.json to explicitly be `0.57.1`, not `^0.57.1`

and delete `node_modules` folder

then do

```
npm i
```

Check [here](http://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21754) for updates regarding the issue

Comment: the same Error my friend!!, it's Happened suddenly

Comment: Yes Check the screenshot in url

Comment: @Gha have u deleted node_modules folder and then npm i

Comment: @Gha check this for resolution same issue posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686605/failed-to-capture-snapshot-of-input-files-for-task-android-studio

Comment: yes Deleted them and npm i , but when try " react-native run-android" i have Faild Build App, i check the issue , but i'm not use Andriod Studio , i use Genymotion Emulator

Comment: after i downgrading  to 0.57.2 i got error like this  "the development server returned response error code:500"

Comment: @FarisDewantoro check the last Answer